# Массив из элементов класса javaScript

Tags: ооп, javascript, java

Вообщем, столкнулся с ужасной непонятной проблемой на JavaScript. 
Я не знаю где причина. И что я делаю не так. Вертел как угодно. 
Задача в том, что бы сохранить в массиве (Array) несколько обьектов класса, который я сам описал на JS:

```
// Определяем массив: 
var Users = [];

// А вот как определен класс (используется prototype. Это классы в javaScript): 
var DOUser = function(userSet, id) 
{ 
 // (Код конструктора)

var MemberCode = -1;

var XCode = -1;

var Nickname = "???"; 
 var ID = -1; 
 var UIN = -1;

var Sent = -1; 
 var Money = -1; 
 var Respect = -1; 
}

// Итак, в некоторой функции я пытаюсь сохранить несколько элементом имеющих тип моего класса в мой массив: 
var user = // создание обьекта DOUser .... 
Users.push(user);
```

Ок, все вроде бы отлично, НО! Элемент не добавляется в массив!!
Идет добавление 4 обьектов в массив. А в итоге получается, что там 4 ячейки, равных undefined.

Я проверял проблема имено в Array.push(..). 
Что я делаю не так?(((

﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот прям тут же в консоли firebug накидал аналогичный вариант.

```
var X = function(){var y=1;}
var z = [];
z.push(new X())
z.push(new X())
z.push(new X())
z.push(new X())
console.log(z)
```

вывод:

```
 [Object {}, Object {}, Object {}, Object {}]
```

все работает, проблема не в механизме JS. Разберитесь правильно ли вы создаете объекты, в вопросе этот элемент кода опущен.

Comment: спасибо, забыл упомянуть, что работа идет на другом движке и вообще не браузерном. Просто тоже компилятор jS.
Обращусь в саппорт.